I can't dowload dashboard, PowerBi Service with Python
try in many ways download dashbord from power bi service, but my python script not working.
This is my python file.
I have my client_id and client_secret from Azure in Registration Apps. And Tenant_id is now Entra id, and this key is from here.
import msal
import requests
import os

# Datos de tu aplicación registrada en Azure AD
client_id = 'my client id'
client_secret = 'my client secret'
tenant_id = 'my entra id'
authority = f'https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant_id}'
scope = ['https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api/.default']

# Crear un objeto de aplicación confidencial
app = msal.ConfidentialClientApplication(
    client_id,
    authority=authority,
    client_credential=client_secret
)

# Obtener un token de acceso
result = app.acquire_token_for_client(scopes=scope)

# Verificar si el token se obtuvo correctamente
if 'access_token' in result:
    access_token = result['access_token']
    print('Token obtenido exitosamente.')
else:
    print('Error al obtener el token:', result.get('error_description'))
    raise SystemExit(1)

# IDs necesarios para la solicitud
workspace_id = 'YOUR_WORKSPACE_ID'  # ID del espacio de trabajo (grupo)
report_id = 'YOUR_REPORT_ID'        # ID del reporte

# URL de la API de exportación de reportes
url = f'https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/groups/{workspace_id}/reports/{report_id}/Export'

# Encabezados de la solicitud
headers = {
    'Authorization': f'Bearer {access_token}',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
}

# Realizar la solicitud
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

# Ruta donde deseas guardar el archivo
save_path = 'C:\\example_path\\PBI_TEST\\report.pbix'

# Crear directorio si no existe
os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(save_path), exist_ok=True)

# Guardar el reporte en un archivo
if response.status_code == 200:
    with open(save_path, 'wb') as file:
        file.write(response.content)
    print('Reporte descargado exitosamente en', save_path)
else:
    print(f'Error al descargar el reporte: {response.status_code}, {response.text}')


My message error this Error to download report: 401
I'm really newby in this process.
